# How can I manage authentication in next 13.4 with external api with redux toolkit as a state management?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I am implementing authentication with next 13.4 app dir with redux toolkit as a state management, I am using django as my backend api endpoint and sending session with jwt token. I am calling getMe api to get currently logged in user if they sent jwt with request. and want to store the response(current user) for later uses so I don't have to call getMe over and over again and I am dispatching a redux action for storing the result on my store. based on store data I am showing a user is logged in or not. But the problem is store data is globally persisted on server, How can i make that per user session so I can check a user is logged in or not only for hard page reload .

Root layout.tsx

```
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const cookiesList = cookies().getAll()

  const user = await getMe(cookiesList)
  if (user) {
    store.dispatch(setUser(user))
  }

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className='rbt-header-sticky'>
        <Providers preloadedState={{
          auth: {
            user: user
          }
        }}> {/* redux toolkit provider */}
          <Header />
          <MobileMenu />
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

store.ts

```
import userReducer from '@/components/Auth/authSlice';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const createStore = (preloadedState = {}) => {
    return configureStore({
        reducer: {
            auth: userReducer
        },
        devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
        preloadedState
    })
}

const store = createStore();

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch

export default store;
```